# Limit the size of a PDF file

Tags: php, compression, ghostscript

i have written a script in PHP which compress Pdf Files using GhostScript.

It also works as intended, but I would like to add that it compresses each PDF file to 2mb. Is there any possibility?

So far I discard files larger than 2mb. The following code is used:

```
class PdfCompressor {

    private string $inputPdf;
    private string $outputPdf;
    private float $compatibilityLevel;
    private int $compressionLevel;
    private array $pdfSettings;
    private string $command;

    /**
     * @param $inputPdf
     * @param $outputPdf
     * @param $compatibilityLevel
     * @param $compressionLevel
     */
    public function __construct($inputPdf, $outputPdf, $compatibilityLevel, $compressionLevel) {
        $this->inputPdf = $inputPdf;
        $this->outputPdf = $outputPdf;
        $this->compatibilityLevel = $compatibilityLevel;
        $this->compressionLevel = $compressionLevel;
        $this->pdfSettings = [
            'default' => 'default',
            'ebook' => 'ebook',
            'printer' => 'printer',
            'screen' => 'screen',
            'prepress' => 'prepress'
        ];
        $this->command = 'gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel='.$this->compatibilityLevel.' -dPDFSETTINGS=/'.$this->pdfSettings['ebook'].' -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -dCompressionLevel=' . $this->compressionLevel . ' -sOutputFile=' . $this->outputPdf . ' ' . $this->inputPdf;
    }

    /**
     * Compresses a PDF file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function compressPdf() {
        if (!file_exists($this->inputPdf)) {
            echo 'Pdf konnte nicht gefunden werden';
            exit;
        } else {
            exec($this->command, $output, $return);
        }
        if ($return === 0) {
            if(file_exists($this->outputPdf) && filesize($this->outputPdf) <= 2*1024*1024) {
                echo 'Pdf wurde erfolgreich komprimiert';
            }else{
                unlink($this->outputPdf);
                echo 'Komprimierte PDF-Datei überschreitet die Maximale Größe von 2MB.';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Pdf konnte nicht komprimiert werden';
        }
    }
}

$pdfName = 'wissenschaft';

$inputPdf = $pdfName.'.pdf';
$outputPdf = $pdfName.'_compressed.pdf';
$compatibilityLevel = 1.4;
$compressionLevel = 1;

$pdfCompressor = new PdfCompressor($inputPdf, $outputPdf, $compatibilityLevel, $compressionLevel);
$pdfCompressor->compressPdf();
```

I tried to send it through a loop until it had the required size, which didn't work, so it went into an infinite loop.

Comment: Things will compress, but not indefintely. You cannot keep looping to compress the data multiple times until it gets to a specific size. In short, you cannot compresss the complete works of Shakespeare into a 2mb lump of grissle regardless of how many times you try and re-compress the previous compression

Comment: As above...it depends on what the content of the file is. You can't squash something down more than it's physically possible to squash it. It's quite analagous to trying to fit an object into a smaller box - there's a limit to how small you can go, no matter how flexible the object is. Anything else would be a form of magic. Your goal of 2MB appears to be arbitrary and is likely to be unrealistic for some files. It's not clear why you actually want this limit? What issue are you trying to solve with that really? This has the strong smell of an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do exactly. But if you really have to keep it under 2MB, you should consider splitting up the pdf's. This still seems like a silly solution as the total size will be the same but it's just split up over multiple files..

Comment: @Wimanicesir it is a little silly but i tried it like that

Comment: It's still not clear why you think you even need to do this at all. Why 2MB?

Comment: 1. There is no way to predict a compressed file's size without compressing it. 2.Trying to compress data that has already been compressed will generally _increase_ the size of the result. So if the resulting file is larger than your arbitrary limit the you either need to put less data in it, split it, increase the level of the compression, or raise the limit on the file size.